# Is it true that there is some Jyotirling that still floats on air?

Tags: jyotirlinga

I have heard that there is a jyotirlinga that from starting till now floats in air. Please tell me which jyotirlinga is that and what is the reason of its floating in air.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  Here are pictures of all 12 Jyotirlingas: http://www.walkthroughindia.com/festivals/the-12-jyotirlingas-of-the-great-god-of-gods-lord-shiva/  They're all on the ground as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 5):

It was in Somnath at Gujarat.It floats due to smart use of construction materials.It does not float anymore due to destruction caused by Islamic invaders.

@Vineet Menon

You can find a brief description at this [link](http://www.speakingtree.in/allslides/lesser-known-facts-about-somnath-temple).Alternatively,the [book](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Jai_Somnath.html?id=5FVnJ47N1pkC) Jai Somnath by K.M.Munshi -ISBN:9788184617696 is providing a detailed account of the temple.

Comment: Hi. Please cite sources for your claim. We encourage well sourced answers.